# WooCommerce product categories are not displayed properly in menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I got this strange behavior in Wordpress, I have about 90 product categories/subcategories.

All the related functions are working fine, except when I go to Appearance -> Menu and try to add product categories to my menu.

The thing is that only two pages of product categories are viewed with many missing categories.

please see the attached screenshot.

[image: Missing subcategories in product category menu]

I am using Woocommerce v3.3.4

Server info:

[image: Woocommerce Server status]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ‘Tools’ tab inside the WooCommerce > System Status of your WordPress administration panel. Here you first use the ‘Recount terms’ button and after that use the ‘Clear transients’ button. This will force the system to recount all the products the next time a category is loaded.

Answer (score -3):

File Manager >> public_html >> wp-admin >> includes >> nav-menu.php

search for **paginate** there is two it will be the one in line 692 (it was for me).

// Paginate browsing for large numbers of objects.
    $per_page = 50;

Change 50 to your needs

Also add to child theme functions.php

Comment: Please do NOT do what this answer instructs. You must NEVER edit core WP files!